# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Create Locator" tool

Tags: qgis, geocoding, geolocation, address

I would like to create my own locator in QGIS based on our address points and streets segments datasets instead of using web services like OSM, Google or Nominatim. Is there a tool available for that in QGIS, similar to [ArcGIS's locator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geocoding/about-locators.htm)?

Comment: What functionality do you want exactly? From the ArcGIS description you might be able to load your data as a layer, but make it invisible, and then search the attribute table when you want to do lookups.

Comment: The functionality that I'd like is to be able to geocode addresses based on our own structured data. ArcGIS Locator provides a tool to build a dataset (the Locator) and another one to geocode an attribute table containing addresses against this Locator. All sort of abbreviations handling, street name components ordering, fuzzy matchs and what else are done within a black box that, I should admit, works pretty well. I need to use our own addresses dataset to be able to leverage other informations already in our address dataset, so all the web services in the world won't help me here...

Comment: Maybe run an apache solr service locally and connect to it and use https://github.com/jagodki/SolrSearch ? QGIS does have an extensible locator architecture and there's various plugins that do that, so making one that searches your data should be feasible, depending on your data structure. You might have to pay to have it developed though, reach out to QGIS developer list maybe?